# I tried to run a .exe I made with ursina and I got this error

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, game-engine, ursina

This is the error I get when running the application.

```
File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "ursina\main.py", line 28, in __init__
  File "direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 339, in __init__
  File "direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 1024, in openDefaultWindow
  File "direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 1059, in openMainWindow
  File "direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 769, in openWindow
  File "direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 749, in <lambda>
  File "direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 821, in _doOpenWindow
  File "direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 650, in makeDefaultPipe
  File "direct\directnotify\Notifier.py", line 130, in error
Exception: No graphics pipe is available!
Your Config.prc file must name at least one valid panda display
library via load-display or aux-display.
```

Also I only have one Config.prc which is the panda3d one from ursina.

Comment: Okay, and what should we answer now?

Comment: I need help solving this,I tried searching the file but I don't know  what to do with it,I usually develop with PyQt5 not ursina,i'm still learning and need someone's help,do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried doing what the last sentence of the error message suggests?

Comment: Welp,I don't know how to do that,i'm very new to ursina engine.

Comment: Okay. You might want to ask a question about it.

Comment: I found something related to what it says at the end:
"Rename your Config.prc file to something else. Otherwise, you are overriding Panda3D's default configuration file, which is also called Config.prc."
The problem here is that I only have 1 Config.prc file and it's from Panda3d,so what do I need to add?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.